# Should the frame-rate dependency taken into account in the calculation of Vector3.Distance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate, google-cardboard

I have a thesis project where I am moving different game objects with cardboard. The interaction with game objects is done with the cross-hair. Currently, I am grabbing the object and trying to calculate the distance that the object traveled. In other words, I am grabbing the object and move it with cross-hair. Currently, I am calculating the distance like this :

```
distance = (Math.Abs (Vector3.Distance (newPosition, originalPosition)));
```

My question is as follows:

- Should I take into account the framerate dependency and multiply the distance to Time.deltaTime or this distance is framerate independent?

Comment: I have deleted that question because the answer was not clear and did not help me :(

Comment: @Leoverload that link is actually the OP's prior question now deleted ;)

Comment: it wasn't before, can I retire a flag ? ;) @MickyD

Comment: @Leoverload certainly can, just delete the comment above and withdraw close-duplicate vote as necessary :)

Comment: The `Math.Abs` is totally redundant .. and is an absolute distance between a start and current position dependent on the frame-rate? ;) .. Spoiler: It's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I take into account the framerate dependency and multiply the distance to Time.deltaTime or this distance is framerate independent?

No because:

1. you already know the original and new positions
2. distance calculations doesn't involve time even during instantaneous calculations

**Frame rate** or more importantly *time since last update* impacts when you are calculating a **new position** based on *velocity*.  In this case time since last update is used as a scalar.

By the way the line

```
distance = (Math.Abs (Vector3.Distance (newPosition, originalPosition)));
```

...can be simplified to:

```
distance = Vector3.Distance (newPosition, originalPosition);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  but the thing is that I know the originalPosition at the start of the update function and at the end of each update function I am doing newPosition = originaPosition. I am doing it because I don't know the final point of the movement. Is your answer same for this case also?

Comment: @MaqomedRahmanov that's a new question and so you should post it accordlingly but I will say that by `newPosition = originaPosition` then your `distance = 0` anyway so it won't matter in any event. _"I don't know the final point of the movement"_ - well it sounds like you should be taking into account velocity in which case elapsed time becomes important

Comment: final point of movement depends on the user who is going to move the object. I don't understand exactly how should I take into account the velocity?

Comment: That sounds like an excellent new question, consider posting it to SO